# How do I use only portion of parameters of constructors? (Java)

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

I was asked to create an method to add student to an array given their street number(int) and house number(int).
Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```
  Student a = new Student("Abigail", 1, 5);
```

I'm only allowed to use student's street number and house number, which is only a portion of the parameters of constructor.  Is there any way to relate object(Student) just from portion of information?

Here's my constructor:

```
 public Student(String n, int sN, int hN){
        name = n;
        streetNum = sN;
        houseNum = hN;
    }
```

Comment: Use getters/setters

Comment: Just because **you** don't need the additional information in this `Student` object does not mean nobody else doesen't either. All the parameters of a Constructor are concidered to be needed for a valid object. On the other hand: why cant you just ignore the "additional" constructor parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You can create another constructor with less parameters like this:

```
public class Student {

    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "Cookie Monster";
    public static final String DEFAULT_STREET_NUMBER = 46; //Sesame Street Number?   

    private String name;
    private int streetNum;
    private int houseNum;

    public Student(String n, int sN, int hN){
        name = n;
        streetNum = sN;
        houseNum = hN;
    }

    public Student(int sN, int hN){
        this(DEFAULT_NAME, sN, hN);
    }

    public Student(int hN){
        this(DEFAULT_STREET_NUMBER, hN);
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor point: You could continue calling `this(...)` all the way up. So, in the ctor with one param you could do `this(46, hN);` and in the one with two do `this("DEFAULT_NAME", sN, hN);` It helps reduce repetition.

Comment: You are totally right. I just made that way so he can see some of his options. In fact i will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

i think there is two way:

1) Create a constructor like this:

```
public Student(int sN, int hN){
        streetNum = sN;
        houseNum = hN;
    }
```

And use it like :

```
  Student a = new Student(1, 5);
```

2) Or if you don't want to a constructor then use like:

```
  Student a = new Student("", 1, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use null in Construction. For example `new Student(null, 5, 1)` generally this is possible but you overwrite defaults with this method like when the name defaults to `private String name = "Peter"`